# Angular2 compiler turns module 'x' into 'x/index'

Tags: angular, rollup, angular-compiler-cli, angular-compiler

I'm having a hard time to understand why `@angular` compiler changes my modules names:

**directive.ts**

```
import isNil from 'lodash-es/isNil';
...
@Directive({
  selector: '[aColor]',
})
export class AColorDirective { }
```

**tsconfig.aot.json**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "lib": [
      "es2015",
      "dom"
    ],
    "target": "es2015",
    "outDir": "./lib-es2015",
    "baseUrl": "."
  },
  "files": [
    "./directive.ts"
  ],
  "angularCompilerOptions": {
    "strictMetadataEmit": true,
    "skipTemplateCodegen": true,
    "annotateForClosureCompiler": true,
    "genDir": "./lib-es2015",
  }
}
```

then I run `@angular/compiler` by using the `cli` as `ngc -p tsconfig.aot.json`.
I get this as result which doesn't make any sens.

**directive.js**

```
import isNil from 'lodash-es/isNil/index';
...
```

Does anyone know why this happens, or how to fix this. This makes it impossible for `Rollup` to resolve these modules.

Angular compiler: v4.2.4

Angular compiler-cli: v4.1.3

Comment: is XModule your module?

Comment: Yes. but it's already a node module.
I tried with `lodash` as well the result is the same.

Comment: I changed some stuff in the question to clarify that this happens to all modules.